# Alternative to prompt() without using HTML elements in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, electron, html5-canvas

I am making a program in JavaScript that uses the canvas. I want to get user input from the prompt() function, but that has been deprecated in Electron Fiddle that I am using.

What is an alternative to prompt() that does not use any HTML elements?

Comment: What environment are you using?

Comment: Electron Fiddle

Comment: Why can't you use html input?

Comment: New Web Popover API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Popover_API may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Konrad I'm making a game, and I would prefer everything to stay in the canvas, where the game runs.

Comment: Listen for keypress  event on canvas

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) element?

```js
const dialog01 = document.getElementById('dialog01');

document.forms.form01.open.addEventListener('click', e => {
  dialog01.showModal();
});

dialog01.addEventListener('close', e => {
  console.log(document.forms.dialogform.text.value);
});
```

```html
<dialog id="dialog01" closed>
  <p>This is the dialog</p>
  <form method="dialog" name="dialogform">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <button>OK</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
<form name="form01">
  <button name="open" type="button">Open dialog</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no alternative for `prompt()` built into the `Windows` object.

However if you want, there are libraries that do the same thing for you
*but* they work with `html elements`.

[pure popup could help you](https://github.com/dFelinger/PurePopup)

Comment: Do you know if the popup goes on top of all the other elements?